# Jenkinsfile - How to detect destination of pull request

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

so I have a `jenkinsfile` where I have my pipeline. I would like to be able to distinguish between a pull request which is going to the master and pull requests going elsewhere. I have found example code for detecting pull requests - something like this:

```
env.BRANCH_NAME.startsWith('PR-')
```

But is there any way to find out the target of the pull request from some `env.` variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per `https://yourjenkinsurl/pipeline-syntax/globals`:

> CHANGE_TARGET
>      For a multibranch project corresponding to some kind of change request, this will be set to the target or base branch to which the change could be merged, if supported; else unset.

Comment: why couldnt I find that!!! Been searching everywhere.. Will check it out immediately! Thanks!

Comment: The CHANGE_TARGET does not seem to work anymore. Any other solutions?

Comment: I missed the "else unset" part. This shows up for a PR but not for a direct branch push - it simply won't be there so you have to check for it's existence before using it.

Comment: env.CHANGE_TARGET works for me.
But you should only use it when it is a PR.
You can check that with IS_PULL_REQUEST = "${env.CHANGE_ID != null}"
Btw: you can see a list of all available global variables for your jenkins at https://<JENKINS_URL>/env-vars.html/